# C++ using namespace statement

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    static void foo1()
    {

    }
}

using namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass
{
    void foo2()
    {
        ::foo1();
    }    
};
```

The scope resolution operation `::` means using method in the global namespace. Here we can use `::foo1()`. This means method `foo1()` is in the global namespace, am I right?

My question is, does `using namespace ANAMESPACE_NAME` mean we import all elements form the namespace `ANAMESPACE_NAME` into the global namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 3.4.3.4 of the C++2003 standard has an answer:

> A name prefixed by the unary scope operator :: (5.1) is looked up in
>   global scope, in the translation unit where it is used. The name shall
>   be declared in global namespace scope **or shall be a name whose
>   declaration is visible in global scope because of a using-directive**
>   (3.4.3.2).

This paragraph is almost identical in the C++11 FDIS, so this probably also holds in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

No. "using namespace ANAMESPACE_NAME" mean we import all elements into current scope.

You can write something like this:

```
namespace A {
    int i = 10, j = 20;
}

int f()
{
    using namespace A;  // injects names from A into the global scope.
    return i * j;       // uses i and j from namespace A.
}

int k = i * j; // Error: undefined variant i and j.
```

Comment: +1: Using-directives don't always have to be in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

> Here we can use ::foo1(). This means method foo1() is in the global namespace, am I right?

Yes thats correct. It means call the method named `foo1()` defined in global namespace.
This is called as **Qualified Namespace Lookup**.

> do "using namespace ANAMESPACE_NAME" mean we import all elements in the ANAMESPACE_NAME namespace into global namespace?

Yes, it imports all elements from the `ANAMESPACE_NAME` namespace in to current namespace.
It is called as an **using directive**.
If you want to import just specific element in current type use, **using declaration**.

format is:

> using ANAMESPACE_NAME::element_name;

Answer (score 0):

YEs -

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/