# What Does Specifying a Class Name in a using Statement Do?

Tags: c++, class, scope, using, named-scope

Given the following:

```
namespace Foo{
class Bar{
    static const auto PRIVATE = 0;
    const int private_ = 1;
    void ptivateFunc() { cout << 2; }
public:
    static const auto PUBLIC = 3;
    const int public_ = 4;
    void publicFunc() { cout << 5; }
};
}
```

The statement `using Foo::Bar;` compiles... But I'm not sure what it's providing me access to. Can anyone explain what the point of that statement would be and what it would give me access to with respect to `Bar` versus simply doing a `using namespace Bar`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ using namespace statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701891/c-using-namespace-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace):

> using `ns_name::name`;  (6)
>   (...)
>   6) using-declaration: makes the symbol `name` from the namespace `ns_name` accessible for unqualified lookup as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this using-declaration appears.
>
> using namespace `ns_name`;    (5)
>   5) using-directive: From the point of view of unqualified name lookup of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, **every name from namespace-name** is visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and namespace-name.

So basically you can write `Bar` instead of `Foo::Bar` outside of the namespace `Foo` (but inside the scope of the using-declaration), while other symbols from the namespace `Foo` still need the full name.

If you use `using namespace Foo` you can access all symbols in `Foo` by their local name without the explicit `Foo::`.

Comment: You may want to include that this is limited to the scope where the using declaration is introduced.

Comment: "as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this using-declaration appears" - so it is in the quote, but i also added it to the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to use `Bar` without `Foo` namespace.

Comment: So it's the exact same as `using namespace Foo;` but it limits the scope exposure to `Bar`?

Comment: @JonathanMee, exactly.